# Writing async javascript functions

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, npm

I'm fairly familiar with nodejs now, but I have never tried to build a module before. I was curious to a bit abut async functions.

1. If you are writing a function that just returns a value, if it worth it to make it async for example, should this be written async?:

   exports.getFilename = function () {
       return filename;
   }
2. Next, when writing a async function, is writing a function with a callback enough for performance, or is it recommended to thread it using a threading library as well?

Sorry for the somewhat obvious question, I noramlly am the one calling these functions

Comment: 1. No 2. There are no threads in JavaScript/Node.

Comment: Okay, I know it is possible to use a external library to thread and there is cluster, but I did not know that there is no support for actual threads. Thanks!

Comment: @RandomUser Node does use multi-threading (as well as multi-process for clusters). It just doesn't make any of the others available to JavaScript code. They're just for [native addons](http://nodejs.org/api/addons.html) to support developing asynchronous APIs.

Comment: Node.js does enable javascript code to use threading via threading libraries on NPM. Note that there are quite a few threading libraries out there. I think the OP is well aware of this but apparently the commenters are not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Callbacks and asynchronousness are two separate things though they are related since in javascript callbacks is the only mechanism to allow you to manage control flow in asynchronous code.

Weather or not non-asynchronous functions should accept callbacks depend on what the function does. One example of a type of function that is not asynchronous but is useful to supply a callback is iteration functions. `Array.each()` is a good example. Javascript doesn't allow you to pass code blocks so you pass functions to your iteration function.

Another example is filter functions that modify incoming data and return the modified version. `Array.sort()` is a good example. Passing a function to it allows you to apply your own conditions for how the array should be sorted.

Actually, filtering functions have a stronger reason for accepting functions/callbacks since it alters the behavior of the algorithm. Iteration functions are just nice syntactic sugar around for loops and are therefore a bit redundant. Though, they do make code nicer to read.

Weather or not a function should be asynchronous is a different matter. If it does something that takes a long time to compute (like I/O operations or large matrix calculations) then it should be made asynchronous. How long is "long" depends on your own tolerance. Generally for a moderately busy website a request shouldn't take more than 100ms to complete (in other words, you should be able to handle 10 hits per second at minimum). If an operation takes longer than that then you should split it up and make it async otherwise you'll risk making the site unresponsive to other users. For really busy websites you shouldn't tolerate operations that take longer than 10ms.

From the above explanation it should be obvious that just accepting a function or callback as an argument does not make a function asynchronous. The simplest pure-js way to make something async is to use setTimeout to break long calculations. Of course, the operation still happens in the same thread as the main Node process but at least it doesn't block other requests. To utilize multi-core CPUs on your servers you can use one of the threading libraries on NPM or clusters to make your function async.

Comment: I think there's a difference between a parameter that accepts a function and a "callback", which would be a specific use case for accepting a function. A "callback" is a function you will call at some later point, because your async code finishes or an event is fired, etc., but that's not entirely the same as providing a function which will be used to sort the elements of an array. I think it's important to be clear on what we actually mean by "callback".

Comment: @JonSurrell: Not so in javascript programming. A function that will be called by another function is often referred to as `callback` regardless of weather it's synchronous or asynchronous. I realize that other programming languages and Computer Science has other definitions of the term. But javascript programmers have used it to mean simply a function that is passed as a parameter. This use is common in discussion boards, wiki articles, blogs and books.

Comment: @JonSurrell: This is not the only word where the specific definition in javascript differs to the general definition. Javascript uses the word "context" for example to refer to object binding and inheritance chain. Generally "context" refers to how code is evaluated - for example in definition context or expression context. Perl for example can execute code in list context (when a function/expression is called in a list construction), a scalar context and undef context.

Comment: Interesting points. MDN refers to `callback` as the parameter for [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) but `compareFunction` as the parameter for [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort). I do think there is something inherently (and subtly) different about the purpose of these functions. The MDN terminology seems to reflect the [ECMAScript spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.18).